# Sending String to 2 textviews

Tags: android, string, android-bluetooth

I have made an app that communicates via Bluetooth. It receives a string from a hardware device and displays the string to a text view.
I want to know how to take that string and split it to send 1 half to one TextView and the other half to another TextView within the handler. At the moment it sends the string to 1 TextView as it is coded to.

```
mHandler = new Handler(){
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg){
            if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){
                String readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj,
                        StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                textView.setText(readMessage);
            }
```

Comment: You should give more explanation with a piece of code.

Comment: Share your code and we will try help you out

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: How do i add the code on here after already asking a question?

Comment: You edit the question @DoinkyDeano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int middle = readMessage.lenght() / 2;
textView1.setText(readMessage.subString(0, middle));
textView2.setText(readMessage.subString(middle));
```